# delete multiple items from tableview list in swift

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview, selection

After I checked multiple items in my tableview list I want to delete them from my list and add them to a favourites list.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    //this is to make multiple selections in list
    tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)?.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark

    //this gives me an array for rowsSelected
    let rowsSelected = self.tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows!.map{$0.row}
    completeList.removeAtIndex(rowsSelected)

    //tried this alternative - not sure what type "selection" is here
    let selection = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows{
    completeList.removeAtIndex(rowsSelected)
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

To be able to delete the items from your tableview you should start deleting in reverse.This way the problem you're having wont occur.Such as if you want to delete say 2,4,6 from an array [1,2,3,4,5,6]you should start deleting from 6 to 2.To be more clear you should start deleting from the bottom most cell then the index wont become out of range.

Example:

```
if let indexPaths = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows  {
    //Sort the array so it doesn't cause a crash depending on your selection order.
    let sortedPaths = indexPaths.sorted {$0.row > $1.row}
            for indexPath in sortedPaths {

                let count = array.count

                var i = count-1

                for i in stride(from: i, through: 0, by: -1) {

                    if(indexPath.row == i){

                        array.remove(at: i)

                    }
                }
            }
            tableView.deleteRows(at: sortedPaths, with: .automatic)
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 3**

going off of EmirC's answer I ran into difficulty with it deleting rows that were earlier in the indexPaths array then having a discontinuity and eventually crashing so I came up with this solution which sorts the array to solve the problem.

```
    if let indexPaths = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows  {

        let sortedArray = indexPaths.sorted {$0.row < $1.row}

        for i in (0...sortedArray.count-1).reversed() {

            Tasks.remove(at: sortedArray[i].row)
        }
        tableView.deleteRows(at: sortedArray, with: .automatic)
    }
```

Comment: This logic is correct. However I realized that this causes a crash depending on with which order you select the rows. The index paths also have to be sorted from big to small. Correcting as "let sortedPaths = indexPaths.sorted {$0.row > $1.row}" solves the issue. Thanks for pointing out that the array needs to be sorted:).